# Java - Message when closing JFrame Window

Tags: java, swing, window, jframe

I have a Java Program containing a class **Application** inheriting from JFrame.

I want to display a message which asks the user if he wants to exit the program upon clicking the X button at the top right of the window.

This is my code so far:

I got this code from a tutorial I found online.  I coded the WindowClosing event handler myself.  However, I have trouble registering the window listener (addWindowListener).  It is telling me that WindowAdapter is abstract and cannot be instantiated.

How can I solve this problem please?

Comment: Are you sure you want to solve this problem? (TM) ;-)

Comment: Of course I want to solve it ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Basically, you got it almost correct. There are a few things not put together correctly and a typo.

First remove your `WindowClosing` method (it's `window`, not `Window`)
Then replace your `addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter());` with the code below

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    int confirmed = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
        "Are you sure you want to exit the program?", "Exit Program Message Box",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    if (confirmed == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
      dispose();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: @Matthew If you are using Java 5(+), you can use the `@Override` annotation to show that you were intending to extend a method in the superclass, i.e. `windowClosing`. You would have then received a compile error for your typo.

Answer (score 2):

i got this in two minutes coding....

First is set the j frame default closing event in Exit_on_close. Second create a class called "Window Closing Event Handler" and then call it in the i nit stage.

```
private void WindowClosingEventHandler(){ addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() { @Override public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) { int confirmed = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to exit this application?", "Exit Program Message Box",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    if (confirmed == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        try{
            String login=txtuserid.getText();
            Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/repair", "root", "");
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            String update = "UPDATE user set User_Status=0 where UserID='"+ login +"'";
            st.executeUpdate(update);  
            dispose();
            Login2 dialog = new Login2(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }catch(SQLException | HeadlessException q){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, q);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else{
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok trying again.

You cannot create a *new WindowAdapter* because WindowAdapter is abstract. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated. You would need to create a subclass of WindowAdapter and implement its abstract methods as public.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html