# confirmation before press YES to exit program in Java

Tags: java, swing, window, jframe, joptionpane

```
private void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt)                               
    {                                   
        int confirmed = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Exit Program?","EXIT",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(confirmed == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {
            dispose();
        }
    }
```

I want to close program by pressing Close Window Button with confirmation...But when I choose "No" to back to my Jframe, it still helps me to exit the program???

Comment: I'm sorry it's not clear what you're asking

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Window there got 3 options right? 1 is minimize, 1 is expand, and 1 is close program...i want to make that close button when i press it, it come out a confirmation...and i cant do it...

Comment: Check this SO answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19675197/1686291

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Message when closing JFrame Window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419947/java-message-when-closing-jframe-window)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what i understand you want something like this

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    int confirmed = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
        "Are you sure you want to exit the program?", "Exit Program Message Box",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    if (confirmed == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
      dispose();
    }
  }
});
```

If you want to use it on  some button do similiar function to button. Put listener on it and do same. But I'm not sure if I get your question right. But If you want to use button use **ActionListener** and **action performed** method.

check question - [Java - Message when closing JFrame Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419947/java-message-when-closing-jframe-window)

Comment: But i cant add that "addWindowsListener" for myself..since the code is auto generated with my program

Comment: What do you mean by that? You use Window builder? if yes then you still can modify and add anything you like to any of your gui parts

Comment: Should adding else under the if condition there

    if(confirmed == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
                this.dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            }

working well now

Answer (score 5):

```java
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

// ...

frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
        int resp = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Are you sure you want to exit?",
            "Exit?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (resp == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        } else {
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's working for me.

```
private void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
    int confirmed = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Exit Program?","EXIT",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if(confirmed == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    {
        dispose();
    }
} else {
     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```