# Swing - Closing a Frame (Window) or not depending on popup choice

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying that when a user tries to close a window in the normal way (clicking on the X) a popup shows up saying "Are you sure you want to close this window?" and then if he chooses "No", I want the window not to close, which is closing wether he chooses Yes or No.

My current code for this listener is:

```
frmContactarEspecialista.addWindowListener(new FrameWindowListener());    

private class FrameWindowListener extends WindowAdapter {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
            int salir = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frmContactarEspecialista, "Si cierra esta ventana se descartará el email, ¿continuar?", "Salir",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);

            if (salir != 0){

            }
        }
    }
```

After marking my post as duplicate, I alredy tried that with:

```
private class FrameWindowListener extends WindowAdapter {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
            int salir = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frmContactarEspecialista, "Si cierra esta ventana se descartará el email, ¿continuar?", "Salir",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

            if (salir == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                System.out.println("do nothing");
            }
        }
    }
```

And it prints `"do nothing"` but still closes the window.

what should I change or put into the `if` so it doesn't close the window?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [confirmation before press YES to exit program in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330682/confirmation-before-press-yes-to-exit-program-in-java)

Comment: hi @IginoBoffa , I tried that and it keeps on closing, plus idk what to put in dispose() method

Comment: First you should set your frame like jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: ok that worked @newuserua_ext what do I have to put into the if now when choosing YES?

Comment: if yes you should call  dispose(); or System.exit(0) method.

Comment: but disposed isn't defined?

Comment: already defined in WindowEvent; arg0.getWindow().dispose();

Comment: that woked @newuserua_ext , you can post an answer with everything you've said if you want so i can mark it as a correct answer! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!
First you have to add something to your frame.

```
nameofyourframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

So, when you press X, the window won't close at all.
Now let's go to your listener.

```
if(salir != 0){
    nameofyourframe.dispose();
}
```

So, if the answer is yes, it will close your program and window, if no nothing will happen!

Comment: hello, thank you, but I don't wanna close the whole program, just the window where i am